# How do I pass in a parameter to a function in an array?

Tags: javascript

So let's say I have an array of functions. How do I pass each function a value?

Here is a silly example:

```
var poopSong =[

function(this){ console.log('this is '+this);},
function(this){ console.log('that is '+this);},
function(this){ console.log('you are '+this);},

];

poopSong("poop")[1];
```

Comment: You meant `poopSong[1]("poop");`, right? Just use a `forEach` loop.

Comment: Why wouldn't you want to use an `array` of `arguments` which you can loop over an call one function with each of the arguments in the `array`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you have to change the parameter you pass, `this` is a reserved keyword and I don't think you want to use it. Of course you can refer to `this` in the `console.log()`. However, I don't think that this is what your want. That being said the declartion of `poopSong` should be something like the following:

```
var poopSong = [
    function(a){ console.log('this is '+a);},
    function(b){ console.log('that is '+b);},
    function(c){ console.log('you are '+c);},
];
```

Then you can pass an argument to these functions as below:

```
poopSong[0]('you value');
```

We use the square brackets and an index to get an item of an array and since in our case the item is a function we can call it using parentheses and passing the corresonding arguments.

```js
var poopSong =[
    function(a){ console.log('this is '+a); },
    function(b){ console.log('that is '+b); },
    function(c){ console.log('you are '+c); }
];

poopSong[0]("1");
poopSong[1]("2");
poopSong[2]("3");
```

Comment: @SonyThePony You are welcome ! I am glad that I helped :)

Answer (score 2):

Just iterate through the array:

```
for(int i = 0; i < poopSong.Length; i++){
     poopSong[i]("poop"); //not poopSong("poop")[i];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

poopSong is the array, so to get to an item, use an index. And since the items in the array are functions, execute a function with (), passing in a parameter ("value");

```
poopSong[1]("value");
```

Now if you want to got through each item, use a loop?

```
for(var i = 0; i < poopSong.length; i++)
{
    poopSong[i]("value");
}
```

or in the world of functional programing, use forEach

```
poopSong.forEach(function(item){ item("value"); });
```

is this what you are really after, cause its pretty basic stuff, or am I missing something.

Secondly, don;t use the word `this` as a parameter, its a reserved word and has a whole other context in JavaScript

Comment: what if I just wanted to execute the function at index 1 without cycling through the entire array?

(I could use a conditional inside the for loop to check what index we are at) but can I directly access the function at index 1?

Comment: um, yes of course you can access the function at index 1, without going through the whole array, `poopSong[1]("value")` does exactly that.

Comment: Such a daft moment, I  was working on map methods and the answer was so simple but I was processing what I had just learned, thanks for your patience, this community never disappoints with their patience.